# Craft backup "mysqldump: not found..."

Tags: back-up

I'm getting an error message when trying to back up the Craft DB.

```
2019-09-04 10:21:09 [-][1][6eba342acf082a62ea47300d68faddf4][error][yii\base\Exception] yii\base\Exception: Could not create backup: The shell command "mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/var/www/html/storage/runtime/temp/my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --single-transaction --no-data --result-file="/var/www/html/storage/backups/client-name_190904_172109_fnrhjpwxac_v3.2.10.sql" craft && mysqldump --defaults-extra-file="/var/www/html/storage/runtime/temp/my.cnf" --add-drop-table --comments --create-options --dump-date --no-autocommit --routines --set-charset --triggers --no-create-info --ignore-table=craft.assetindexdata --ignore-table=craft.assettransformindex --ignore-table=craft.sessions --ignore-table=craft.templatecaches --ignore-table=craft.templatecachequeries --ignore-table=craft.templatecacheelements --ignore-table=craft.cache --ignore-table=craft.templatecachecriteria craft >> "/var/www/html/storage/backups/client-name_190904_172109_fnrhjpwxac_v3.2.10.sql"" failed with exit code 127: sh: 1: mysqldump: not found in /var/www/html/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/controllers/UtilitiesController.php:343
```

I'm not sure where to look to solve this. How may I get the DB to back up?

Answer (score 2):

Your server seems to be missing the shell command `mysqldump`, contact your IT-Specialist and tell him you need that to be installed you can backup your website.

Or if you plan on installing it yourself, this should do the trick.

Excerpt  from there:

```sh
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-5.7
```

If it's not able to find the package, try entering the statement till the `mysql` part and then hold `tab` it should then show you all available versions which you can install.

Comment: Or it could be installed, but it's not available to PHP. The easiest way to do that is with through the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about that, thanks for the reminder.

use `phpinfo(); die;` to view just about all settings in your PHP-installation including your PATH environment variable (as far as I know).